# Embed a .doc/.docx/.odf/.pdf/.ppt/.pptx file in html and render them

Tags: javascript, django, iframe, amazon-s3, embed

I have few documents stored in s3. The formats they are in are not in my control. I need to render/view them in my html page.

When I used the below code it is downloading the file when i load that tab instead of rendering them.

```
<iframe src="https://abcd.amazonaws.com/bucket1/attach/abc.doc">  </iframe>
```

My application is written in python, django.

Can you help me with any plugins/javascripts or anything that can help me solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it using Google Viewer.
`<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview url=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>`